# Scrape table header from investing.com

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from investing.com. My code is working except from the table header.
My "columns" variable has the names as: data-col-name = "abc", but I don't know how to extract them as column_names.

```
table_rows = soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr")

table = []
for i in table_rows:
    td = i.find_all("td")
    row = [cell.string for cell in td]
    table.append(row)
    
columns = soup.find("thead").find_all("th")
column_names = 

df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data=table, columns=column_names)
df_dji = df_dji.append(df_temp)
```

Comment: you have to do like with `rows` - use `for`-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.text` instead of `.string`

```
columns = soup.find("thead").find_all("th")
#print(columns)

column_names = [cell.text for cell in columns]
print(column_names)
```

or use `.get_text()` or even `.get_text(strip=True)`

```
column_names = [cell.get_text() for cell in columns]
print(column_names)
```

---

Official documentation shows `.string` (`.text` is unofficial method in new versions but probably was official in older versions) but here `.string` doesn't work - maybe because there is another object `<span>` inside `<th>`. And `get_text()` get all strings from all elements in `th` and create one string.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to get value form `data-col-name=` then use

- `cell['data-col-name']`
- `cell.get('data-col-name')`
- `cell.attrs['data-col-name']`
- `cell.attrs.get('data-col-name')`

(and the same is with `cell['id']` or `cell['class']`)

```
column_names = [cell['data-col-name'] for cell in columns]

column_names = [cell.get('data-col-name') for cell in columns]

# etc.
```

`attrs` is normal `dictionary` so you can use `attrs.get(key, default_value)`, `attrs.keys()`, `attrs.items()`, `attrs.values()` or use like dictionary with `for`-loop.

Comment: I added example how to get value from `data-col-name`